# Node wrong directory

Tags: node.js

I have moved from Ubuntu to MacOS High Sierra and now I am facing the following problem. I hope somebody can help me :-)

I have installed NVM and NPM and on Ubuntu it used to be under `/usr/bin/nodejs`

Now it is installed under `/Users/**USERNAME**/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node`

This is creating a bug problem because we are all working on the same project and the **USERNAME** is not the same as mine.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why does is matter for your project where the node binaries are installed?

Comment: because I need to specify the node & node_path in the Symfony Project

Answer (score 0):

Create a .env file that all members of your team use. Instead of hard coding your code directory read it from your env file. It can be as simple as

```
NODE_DIRECTORY=/usr/bin/node
```

You each keep a .env file in the same location and don't push it to source control and wherever the hard coded node directory was, instead you use something like env('NODE_DIRECTORY"). I'm fairly sure Symfony supports env files with a function anyway.

Comment: Thank you Prodigle, but this is just a workaround :/

Comment: I understand your concerns but this is common practice :) It helps put all your platform dependent stuff in a customisation file, things like database connection info, where logs should be stored etc. etc. It future proofs your application for if you ever deploy it on a server or need to move it, or if other people start working on your project that for instance use windows. I Promise you that once it's set up you won't need to touch it again

Comment: I need to specify the node directory in the config.yml of Symfony. This file is under score control and also used on production. how should I do that? :/

Answer (score 0):

you could always make a symlink from /usr/bin/nodejs to your nodejs directory. then it would run as normal

Comment: this was my first idea but ... sudo ln -s /Users/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node nodejs

ln: nodejs: Operation not permitted

Comment: It's part of OSX integrity protection. Can't symlink to /usr/bin. You can however to /usr/local/bin if that helps

Comment: I found the following part in the NVM doc.. „You can (but should not?) keep your previous "system" node install, but nvm will only be available to your user account (the one used to install nvm). This might cause version mismatches, as other users will be using /usr/local/lib/node_modules/* VS your user account using ~/.nvm/versions/node/vX.X.X/lib/node_modules/*“ ... so I delete Node&NVM (which node comand was blank) and reinstalled NVM but still the same. Is there anythink I forgott?